# Get json object data on jax-rs

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I have this put method on my web service ,this method consumes a json object ,but how i can get this data inside my method if the method receives  a json object with name,surname,afiliation and country fields?

```
@PUT
@Path("/Updatemember/{nom}/{ape}/{afi}/{nac}")
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String Updatemember(@PathParam("nom")String nombre, @PathParam("ape")String apellido, 
                            @PathParam("afi")String afiliacion, @PathParam("nac")String nacionalidad) throws SQLException
{
    Miembro.update(nombre, apellido, afiliacion, nacionalidad);
    return "Data has been updated";
}
```

edit:
 Now the method is

```
@PUT
@Path("/Updatemember/")
@Consumes({"application/json"})
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String Updatemember(Miembro miembro) throws SQLException
{
    miembro.update();
    return "Se han actualizado los datos del miembro";
}
```

and the class member(miembro in spanish)  has this method ,which works fine.

```
public void update() throws SQLException
{
    Connection conexion = Conexion.GetConnection();
    String sql = "UPDATE miembros SET afiliacion='"+getAfiliacion()+"', nacionalidad='"+getNacionalidad()+"' WHERE nombre='"+getNombre()+"' AND apellidos='"+getApellidos()+"'";
    PreparedStatement pre = (PreparedStatement) conexion.prepareStatement(sql);
    pre.execute();
}
```

Updatemember gives me a Nullpoiter exception,the miembro object is not create but i don't know why.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/consuming_and_producing_json_using

Comment: 1) What JAX-RS implementation are you using (e.g. Jersey, Reaseasy)? 2) Show your JSON 3) Show your Miembro class 4) Any errors in the server log? 5) Did you add the JSON provider?

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature is saying that you take in four path parameters (not json - you can have queryParams as json though).

If you create a class called Member with those parameters as members of the class:

```
@XmlRootElement
 public class Member {
      // public constructor 
      // getters and setters for your fields
 }
```

Then let the class be a parameter to your method and change path to @Path("/UpdateMember/{id}").

If you make sure to have either jackson or moxy on the classpath, your Member parameter should be a valid object-instance of class Member.

Read up on the jersey docs here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json

Comment: I know that it receivies 4 path params but i'm asking because i want that teh method workswith a json object.I've edited my post to add more information.